# Clutter AttributeError: module object has no attribute Stage

Tags: python, clutter, clutter-gui

I am absolute beginner for both Python and Clutter. I copied the following from from a website

```
import clutter

stage = clutter.Stage()
stage.set_size(400, 400)

label = clutter.Label()
label.set_text("Clutter Label Text")
# If no position is given it defaults to the upper most left corner.

stage.add(label)
stage.show_all()

clutter.main()
```

When I try this script to run it I am getting

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Stage'
```

can any one help me on this?

Comment: Did you happen to name your program `clutter.py`?

Comment: yes I named it clutter.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your script file name is not `clutter.py`.

If it is, rename it, and make sure there's no `clutter.pyc` in the same directory.

Otherwise, it prevents import of `clutter` module you want, but imports your own module.

Comment: after changing the name of the file to GUIDemo.py I'm getting the real error ImportError: No module named clutter

Comment: @Dinesh, It means you didn't install clutter (at least to the python interpreter you're using)

Comment: I am using Linux Mint OS. I tried with Synaptic Package manager in that there is libclutter-perl but not python. How should I install python clutter binding

Comment: @Dinesh: how to install something is an entirely separate question.

Comment: Thank you. I will raise as a separate question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/23833256/2243490